# The result on test device is always 100

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this small calculator wich works perfectly fine on the simulator, but if I test and run it on my iPhone 6, the result is always `100`.

It doesn't matter if I round the result at the end or not, there it will give the same result: `100.0`.

```
import UIKit

class maininterfaceVC: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var volltonTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rasterTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var ergebnisLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func berechnenButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vollton = NSString(string: volltonTF.text!).doubleValue
        let raster = NSString(string: rasterTF.text!).doubleValue
        //Strings werden in Double konvertiert

        let ergebnis = ((((vollton - raster) / vollton)*100))
        //Druckkontrast wird ausgerechnet


        ergebnisLabel.text = "\(round(ergebnis*100)/100.0)"
        //Ergebnis wird auf zwei Nachkommastellen gerundet und ausgegeben.

    }
}
```

After figuring out that this is a localization problem with the decimal Pad that i use for the Textfields, i rebuild the program with  a `NSNumberFormatter()` floatConverter, english declarations and english comments.
The updated code is this

```
import UIKit

extension String {

    var floatConverter: Float {
        let converter = NSNumberFormatter()
        converter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result = converter.numberFromString(self) {
            return result.floatValue
        } else {
            converter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let result = converter.numberFromString(self) {
                return result.floatValue
            }
        }
        return 0
    }



class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var densityOfSolid: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var densityOfTint: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!



    @IBAction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

        let solidTF = densityOfSolid.text
        let solid = NSString(string: String(format:"%.2f", solidTF!.floatConverter)).floatValue

        let tintTF = densityOfTint.text
        let tint = NSString(string: String(format: "%.2f", tintTF!.floatConverter)).floatValue


        let result = (((solid - tint) / solid) * 100.0)
        //calculate the Printcontrast


        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
        //give out the result on label.


    }
```

The new problem is a `expected declaration` error after the last bracket.
I don't now why.

Comment: Try using the debugger, or adding print statements, to find out exactly which line is causing the problem. As-is, there don't appear to be any obvious problems.

Comment: First: You should comment your code in english. Second: The same applies to your vars naming. Third: Your title says the result is always 1 and  later on you said it is always 100.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value where you divide by 100 in another variable and print the value to see what is going on.

```
let finalValue = round(ergebnis * 100) / 100.0
println("\(finalValue)")
ergebnisLabel.text = "\(finalValue)"
```

It looks like there may be an issue with dividing an int type by a floating point type, and doing it in the string literal is not able to convert to that value.

So you could also make sure the value you are dividing by `100.0` is a double if you want to do the calculation inline.

```
ergebnisLabel.text = "\(Double(round(ergebnis*100)) / 100.0)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i found the problem. It's not a datatype thing, its the problem that i use the Decimal Pad for the textfields. In the Simulator there is a `.` on the pad and everything works. But on my device is a `,` instead of the `.`  Do you have any go around for this?

Comment: That's an issue with localization, which you can use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html) to take care of for you. Or you could manually replace all occurrences of `,` with `.` in the input into the the text field before converting it to a double.

Comment: Hi, can you please review my new code in the question? :) thank you